# Expectation value of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-integrals

For which $k>0$ process $X=(e^{kW_s^2})_{s \ge 0}$ belong to $\mathcal{L}^2_{\infty }(W)$ and for which belong to $\Lambda ^2_{\infty }(W)$. Set one localization sequence $(\tau_n)_{n \ge 0}$ for local martingale $ \int X dW$

So Ive started from the top and I stacked at the begginig.  I mean: I recall the definition of $\mathcal{L}^2_{\infty }(W)$ and to set the $k$ I need to calculate: $\mathbb{E}\int_0^{\infty}e^{2W_s^2}ds$ and it is $\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{E}e^{2W_s^2}ds$
I have problem with that expectation value. I tried use definition of it because we know that $W_s$~$N(0,s)$.

Can you help me?

Comment: For $s>1/4$, then $E(e^{2W_s^2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2s x^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \infty$.

Comment: can you help me also with $\Lambda ^2_{\infty }(W)$ ? I know that I must show that $\int_0^te^{2kW_s^2}ds < \infty$ fo almost every $t < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

chi-squared random variable with k degrees of freedom is given as
$$\chi^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}{{{X}_{i}}^{2}} $$ where the $X_i$'s are all independent and have $N(0, 1)$ distributions. Also recall
that I claimed that $\chi^2$ has a gamma distribution with parameters $r=k=2$
and $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, thus
$$M_{\chi^{\,2}}(t)=\left(\frac{1}{1-2t}\right)^{\frac{k}{2}},\,\,\,\,|t|<\frac{1}{2}$$ 
on the other hand we know
$$\frac{W_s-0}{\sqrt{s}}\sim N(0,1) $$ 
then
$$\frac{{W_s}^2}{s}\sim \chi^2$$
as a result
$$E\left[e^{2{W_s}^2}\right]=E\left[e^{2s\,\frac{{W_s}^2}{s}}\right]=M_{\chi^{\,2}}\left(2s\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4s}}$$

Comment: thank you :) I've noticed I've make mistake there should be: $\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{E}e^{2kW_s^2}ds=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4ks}}$